# How to find & copy everything between two tags (Including tags)

Tags: html, regex, replace, batch-processing

I am looking for an faster way to find & copy everything between two tags (Including tags) in the many html files I'm handling. I'm currently using sublime to manually copy within each file. The html tag is constant (`<center>` `</center>`) .I've tried using regex to accomplish this with no success ex. "`<center>(.*)</center>`"... What would I type in sublime to accomplish this? OR if there is a better method that a beginner could easily learn I'm open to suggestions!

```
</head>

<body style="background-color:#9b9b9b;">
**<center>
<table width="580" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center"  class ="responsive-table" style="background-color:#3e5b3e;border:solid thin #3e5b3e;" >
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td background="http://app.randomsite.com/js/ckfinder/userfiles//images/banner.jpg" style="padding-top:20px;padding-right:20px;padding-left:20px;" class="hideForMobile"><h1 style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;text-align:right;color:#eee;vertical-align:bottom;text-decoration:none;margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;margin-right:0;margin-left:0;" >some message</h1></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
</center>**
    <!---Start of Banner Image--->
      <td><a href="{{Custom1}}" style="color:inherit;text-decoration:none;" ><img src="http://app.clientcommand.com/js/ckfinder/userfiles//images/top-dollar-ford-banner.jpg" alt="" class="table.responsiveImage" style="display:block;width:100%;border-style:none;" /></a></td>
    <!---End of Banner Image--->
    </tr>
    <tr>
```

Be gentle - I'm new to coding

Comment: If you are sure you won't have nested `<center>` tags then `<center>([\s\S]*?)<\/center>` is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your regex is missing something I think.
with `.*` u get all characters but not a line-feed(newline)
try somthing like this

`<center>(.|\n)*<\/center>`

> breakdown of the changed part
>   
>  `.`= all characters
>  `|` = or
>  `\n` = line-feed(newlines)
>  `(.|\n)*` = zero or more times the line above (greedy so as manny times as posible 
>   
> [see demo](https://regex101.com/r/jI1uP8/1)

if u have more sections at a time u can use a `<center>(.|\n)*?<\/center>`

> breakdown of the changed part 
>  the `?`will make it non-greedy so it will return at the first occurence of `</center>`
>   
> [see demo](https://regex101.com/r/uJ1xE3/1)

Comment: <center>(.|\n)*<\/center>

You just saved my life - Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using regex to parse a markup file.
Consider using [Beautifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to parse a html file and extract inner tag content.

In your case it should be something like:

`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
for centered_content in soup.find_all('center'):
    ...(do what you want)...`